Pandoc 3.2.1, duplicate Footnote ID
I'm using Epubcheck on an Epub file produced by Pandoc v3.2.1 and I'm getting some duplicate footnote reference errors, e.g. Error while parsing file: Duplicate ID "fnref13"
I believe that all the footnote references are generated by Pandoc, all footnotes are inline and have not been given IDs by me. Only a few of the footnotes show this error. I'm not sure how to investigate this problem. Is there a way of getting Pandoc to tell me more about what it's doing?
(I hope this is the right place to post this problem. I used to use te Google group pandoc-discuss but that seems to have disappeared.)
Thank you for any help
What I was doing:
Generating an epub file from a markdown file using Pandoc and the checking it using Epubcheck
I was not expecting to see any errors.

can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?
btw. the google group was marked as spam or something by google. its replacement is https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/discussions/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have found the cause of the problem, so this might be useful to anyone who sees the same symptoms.
There were footnotes embedded in the footnotes and the 'inner' footnote was assigned the same number as the 'outer' one. Hence the duplication.
I've removed the embedding and all is well.
